# Swipe layout alignment issue in recycler view

Tags: android-recyclerview, swipe

[For reference, Click to see the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mehwv.png)

I am using swipe layout in recycler view list item. But when swipe sometime the action button hides.

Any help will be most welcomed